# hide div with animation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

This is my code...the problem is when i click the first div it animate(180 deg) and then disappear...what i want is that when i click on first div it disappear without animation and second div appear with animation..and when i click on second div it also disappear with no animation and third div appear with animation..

please check the code i stuck in it...

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="background:grey">
                text here
            </div>
            <div style="background:blue;display:none">
                text here
            </div>
            <div style="background:green;display:none">
                text here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my script

```
 $('.col-md-6').click(function() {
        var $current = $(this).find('div:visible');
        var $next = $current.next()
        if ($next.length) {
            $current.animate({
                borderSpacing: -360
            }, {
                step: function(now, fx) {
                    $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
                    $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
                    $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                },
                duration: 'slow'
            }, 'swing');
            $next.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: So why do you animate the 'current' div if you want to animate the 'next' div?

Comment: add the code in jsfiddle and provide us the link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uop35wpo/  This is the link...the problem is that when the div rotates the text of next div invert...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want this?

I have updated your code a little assuming that you want to hide the current div and animate the next one.

```
   $('.col-md-6').click(function() {
    var $current = $(this).find('div:visible');
    var $next = $current.next()
    if ($next.length) {
        $current.animate({
            borderSpacing: -360
        }, {
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).hide();
                $next.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
                $next.css('-moz-transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
                $next.css('transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
            },
            complete: function() {
                //$(this).hide();
            },
            duration: 'slow'
        }, 'swing');
        $next.show();
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uop35wpo/

if you want to hide the current div after animating the next div then check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/uop35wpo/1/

Comment: thnx for your code...when i change the 'borderspacing=180' the text of next div invert...

Comment: yes because it rotates 180 degree, here whole div rotates 360 degree(complete rotation) thats why you get the text back to its real position that is on the left. if you make it 180 it will obviously invert it and text will appear to right that is 180 degree from the starting point.

Comment: So..is there any possible way to not invert it..if you suggest any css code so when i the div rotate 180 text show without inverting

Comment: if you want text to be at its starting position for every transition , I would suggest you add the text in a different tag( e.g. span) in the div. and then specify css for that text tag(e.g. span). you can rotate the text tag(i.e span) by 180 degree and set its position dynamically for every transition. so that when div inverts it , the inner span will again rotate it by 180 degree to make a 360 spin ot the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').hide('slow');
```

Using Above code

Comment: From the OP it looks like he wants to hide without animation and reveal with animation.